# How can I map tables from different dataSources in Grails?

Tags: grails, datasource

How can I map tables from different dataSources in Grails?

```
class Classroom {
    static hasMany = [students : Student]
    static mapping = {
        datasource 'school'
    }
}

class Laboratory {
    static hasMany = [students : Student]
    static mapping = {
        datasource 'school'
    }
}

class Student {
    String name
    static mapping = {
        datasource 'person'
    }
}
```

If the three tables are all from the same datasource, then Grails would generate five tables namely `classroom`, `laboratory`, `student`, `classroom_student` and `laboratory_student`.

This code gave me an error : `An association from the table classroom_student refers to an unmapped class: registration.Student`

My questions are:

1) How do I achieve this?

2) In which datasource will `classroom_student` and `laboratory_student` be generated?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How do I achieve this?

GORM doesn't support relationships across data sources.  You would have to write your own queries and keep track of the relationships on your own.

> 2) In which datasource will classroom_student and laboratory_student
>   be generated?

Wherever you created them (see answer to #1).